# Providing the actual measured error instead of weights to the lm function in R (or similar linear fit function)

Tags: r, regression

Is there any way to use the linear fit function or R with my own errors instead of the value weights?

That is, I have a physical experiment in which we know the errors for each point, for instance:

```
> df
    x        y   yerror
1   0 3097.460 55.65483
2  60 4624.340 68.00250
3 121 7013.675 83.74769

> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(0, 60, 121), y = c(3097.46, 4624.34, 7013.675
), yerror = c(55.6548290806827, 68.0024999540458, 83.7476865352112
)), .Names = c("x", "y", "yerror"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there any way to provide this to the **lm** function in R (or a similar one) but to give the actual errors instead of having R calculating the statistical ones? For instance, something like the **LINFIT** function from **IDL language**: http://www.astro.virginia.edu/class/oconnell/astr511/idl_5.1_html/idlea.htm
I see I can give the weights as a parameter to **lm**, but what I want is to give the errors we measured.

EDIT:
I'm putting the code and the output in both R and IDL to see the differences.
**IDL/GDL**

```
X = [0, 60, 121]
Y = [3097.46, 4624.34, 7013.675]
YERROR = [55.6548290806827, 68.0024999540458, 83.7476865352112]

result = LINFIT(X, Y, CHISQR=chi2, COVAR=varco, MEASURE_ERRORS=YERROR, SIGMA=sig)
print, result
      3006.64      31.4443
print, chi2
      24.1395
print, varco
      2755.76     -29.0644
     -29.0644      0.65546
print, sig
      52.4954      0.80960
```

And now in **R**:

```
> lfit = lm(y~x, data=df, weights=yerror^-2)
> summary(lfit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = yerror^-2)

Weighted Residuals:
     1      2      3 
 1.632 -3.955  2.415 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 3006.640    257.920  11.657   0.0545 .
x             31.444      3.978   7.905   0.0801 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 4.913 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9842, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9685 
F-statistic: 62.49 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.08011 

> vcov(lfit)
            (Intercept)          x
(Intercept)  66522.7761 -701.59982
x             -701.5998   15.82237

> vcov(lfit)/4.913^2
            (Intercept)          x
(Intercept)  2755.98492 -29.066714
x             -29.06671   0.655508
```

As you can see the covariance matrix from the lm function in R, is multiplied by the square of the "Residual standard error". If that happens all the time, I guess I can just divide it by it and then calculate the error from the right covariance matrix.
Not only that, but the presented error by R seems multiplied by the "Residual standard error" (almost, it's not really exact).

Comment: The inverse of the error should be a reasonable input for lm's weights.

Comment: Could you explain the exact meaning of `yerror`?

Comment: @ndoogan I tought about that, but then I read the lm documentation and it doesn't seem like it: `weights: an optional vector of weights to be used in the fitting process. Should be NULL or a numeric vector. If non-NULL, weighted least squares is used with weights weights (that is, minimizing sum(w*e^2)); otherwise ordinary least squares is used. See also ‘Details’,`

Comment: @NPE I have some satellite data and each value has the normal statistical error of the sqrt(number of counts), **but** this value must be multiplied by a parameter alpha, that is the noise of the detector (which I get from the background noise of the electronics).

Comment: I think I've misunderstood you *again*... What is different here from your earlier [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14636052/429846)? Is `yerror` the "alpha" you mention in your reply to NPE?

Comment: The FITEXY function is for a completely different case, i.e., where you have errors in **both** x and y. It seems to do something like Deming regression. I believe in your example you should indeed use your errors for weights.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes, I asked that question myself :) But now I need the actual values to use further on and from the help of lm, it looks like the lm function is assigning a value of 1 to sigma(standard deviation), and the multiplying it by provided weights. That way, the result will be correct, but the error in the result won't, since the covariance matrix is being calculated from different values than the ones I have.

Comment: @Roland Sorry, my bad, the correct IDL function is LINFIT: http://www.astro.virginia.edu/class/oconnell/astr511/idl_5.1_html/idlea.htm

Comment: @Roland The thing is, **the fit result will be the same this way, but the estimated error of the result will be different with the 2 methods**. This page explains the problem better, since there is a function in IDL that also uses the weights, called CURVEFIT, and the author had the same issue: http://www.idlcoyote.com/math_tips/sigma.html

Comment: For your example data do you know *what* output your *should* be getting? It is difficult to play with the problem when all we have are some input data here and various IDL code for different example input data. I don't have IDL so can't run the examples on the idlcyote page you link to.

Comment: @jbssm I think, one of us is confused and it's probably you. The confusion most likely comes from the question what your errors actually are. I understand them as measurement uncertainties and if that is a case they should be used for weighting.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: The covariance matrix in R gives me exactly the covar matrix in IDL multiplied by the Residual standard error given by R, strange (do you want me to post the values)? Also, the X error in IDL is 3.80, and in R is 3.978. The difference is small, is true.

Comment: @Roland I admit I might be wrong. In fact if I can be sure I'm wrong and I can just use the values provided by R with the weight=yerror^-2 it would be great. The thing is, that I'm getting different outputs from the function in IDL inputed with actual errors, and the one in R inputed with the weights.

Comment: @jbssm Thanks, and yes, please update the question with the output from R (plus code to generate it) and the output from IDL (and even the code to generate that too if applicable) as you could tag this with `idl` also.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I got it in both R and IDL now. It all seems related to the Residual standard error. I believe that the **lm** function is just multiplying the sigma by that value when it calculated the Chi2 value and hence the problem with the results.